# If I forget to take out the trash and took it to a nearby apartment complex, is it under the $950 rule in California?

Tags: california

In California, there was a couple of times I forgot to move the trash outside the garage door on the garbage collection day, and I took the trash and put it into the big bin in a nearby apartment complex.

The times I drove by that area, that bin was never full anyway.

Is it also under the California $950 rule: that if it involves less than $950, the police will not even do anything, even if for some reason, the apartment is so serious to record all the video and look at it to see a bag was put in their dumpster.

There was a time when I parked in San Francisco and my car window was broken, and it costed $120 to fix, and the police told me they won't do anything at all due to the $950 rule: if the money involved is less than $950, they won't do anything at all.

Comment: The police might not do anything. Assuming it to be true, this covers the criminal aspect of the act. The nearby apartment complex might still sue for civil damages.

Answer (score 1):

The "$950 rule" refers to a recent statutory redefinition of misdemeanor theft i.e. "shoplifting", where the line between felony burglary and misdemeanor shoplifting is $950. This is only applicable to "entering a commercial establishment with an intent to commit larceny while it's open during regular business hours", not applicable to what you did. It is not a crime to put your trash in a neighbors bin, but they could sue you for going so. The relevance of this to police is that they only arrest people for commission of crimes, they do not arrest people for being potentially suable. It is also true that in San Fransisco a (controversial) policy decision was made to not prosecute "lifestyle crimes", but this not not a general rule for California. In general, police are not required to arrest and prosecutors are not required to prosecute except if justified, according to their judgment.

So you could get sued, and the police don't have to be involved.